# A matrix diagonalizable problem

Tags: linear-algebra

Let
\begin{equation*}
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
19 & 2019 \\
2019 & 1
\end{bmatrix}    
\end{equation*}
Which of the following statements are true?

(a) The matrix $A$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{R}$.

(b)  There exists a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ consisting of eigenvectors $\{w_1,w_2\}$ of the matrix $A$ such that $w^T_1 w_2 = 0.$

(c) There exists a matrix $B \in GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ such that $B^3 = A.$

My attempt:
Trace of the matrix is $20$ and determinant is $19-(2019)^2\ne 100$. Therefore eigenvalues cant be $10$ and hence they are distinct.

(a) since eigenvalues are distinct $A$ is diagonalizable.

(b) eigenvectors corresponding to different eigenvalues are orthogonal so (b) is true.

(c) Let eigenvalues of $A$ are $m_1,m_2$. Then $A=P^{-1}.diag(m_1,m_2).P$ for some non-singular matrix $P$. Consider $B= P^{-1}.diag(m_1^{1/3},m_2^{1/3}).P$. Then $B^3=A$.

Am I thinking right? Please help.

Comment: Note A is symmetric.

Comment: The explanation for (a) is not correct. You can have distinct eigenvalues, but non-real, then the matrix would not be diagonalizable over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: In fact, the eigenvalues are real, namely $\pm 3\cdot \sqrt{452938} + 10$. You could also use, that a real symmetric matrix has real eigenvalues.

Comment: Yes. Does my answer for (b) and (c) are right?

Comment: for (b), you need the fact that your matrix is symmetric before you can use the result.

Comment: (c) is correct.